# why are we not asked to import server.crt while connecting from psql to postgres server secured using ssl

Tags: postgresql, ssl, client, psql

This is a very basic question . i have to import the server.crt on the client side java trustore to connect using jdbc to postgres server secured by ssl.
But when i try psql from same machine , it shows the connection as encrypted . How does psql import the server certificate?

psql "postgresql://$POSTGRES_HOST:$PG_PORT/postgres" -U postgres
psql (9.6.18)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cert to set up encryption, without verifying that the cert was signed by the correct authority.  This is what psql does by default if there is no root.crt available and the sslmode is 'require' or below.

JDBC must be configured for, or default to, the equivalent of a sslmode above 'require'.

Comment: thanks jjanes , i have installed postgres on my client machine B which allowed me to use psql . This was the psql which i was using to connect to the server postgres machine A which has the ssl parameter turned on.I didnt have to the pass sslcert parameter from client machine B while using psql to connect to server A. I had checked this with the postgres group also , and i think it is because the postgres ships with same certficates

Comment: Also i think the default mode for jdbc should be require or below it , I had written a jdbc client to connect to postgres server. While passing no sslmode argument in the connection url it is getting connected (default value should be require or less). If use verify-ca or verify-full then it throws an exception asking for cerfificate